# Stream screen over local network to shift processing burden for livestreaming

Tags: network, video, streaming

I have a bit of an odd problem. I'm not too sure if it fits in here, but I thought I might as well try.

I want to start Livestreaming to Twitch TV. The problem is, I can't play a game and transcode/stream at the same time without running out of processing power.

What I want to do is stream a high quality video feed over my local network to another computer that can handle the full transcoding and streaming to Twitch. Is there any combination of programs that will let me do this with minimal processing requirement on the first computer?

Comment: The problem is that what you'd need for such a thing is something that can send a raw, uncompressed video stream to the second computer. Anything else would require processing. You would have to use a wired network connection (Ethernet) in order to have enough performance for it (although I'm not certain if even this would be enough). My question though: Is wiring them together with Thunderbolt an option? You could easily send uncompressed video over that.

Comment: What Mac are you using for your game machine? What kind of hardware does it have on it?

Comment: I'm using a Mid 2011 iMac. It's not the most powerful, but it can handle running games and having a few low requirement programs open in the background. I'm wondering if I could strike a balance between compression and processing cost to get something that can be transmitted over WiFi, but doesn't 'cost' too much to compress down a bit. Both computers have Thunderbolt, so that is also an option.